# Android bluetooth example code doesn't work

Tags: android, bluetooth

This will be an awkward question/statement.

**Background:**
I have an LG G4 and I'm trying to write an app with bluetooth. I'm at a beginners level with android but I understand programming as I code in C at work. IDE, Android Studio 2.3.1

**Issue:**
I have tried a few of the sample projects I have found. 
i.e. Android Sample project BluetoothLeGATT, BluetoothChat. None of these work when I'm doing a search for new devices. They pull up the pairedDevices well just not anything else. I know it's not the phone because I go to the settings and find all the devices I'm looking for, while doing a deviceDiscovery.

**Question**
Has anybody come across this or does anybody have any suggestions on what to do next?

Also, I haven't tried Youtube. This will be my next move and I'll report back if anything changes.

Comment: Post your code, nobody can help you without more information.

Comment: First, you should have tried YouTube before posting here, not after. This  should be your last resort after you've researched everything else. Second, we can't tell you what's wrong with your code without seeing your code. Third, this site is for **specific questions** about **actual problems**, and *Stuff doesn't work* is in no way specific. Please see [ask].

Comment: 1. My bad for not doing Youtube first, I was trying to do some of this in parallel  
2. I didn't post my code because I was using the Android sample code. Their code "huge"-ish...plus, I would just be posting sample code that everyone has access to.  
3. I'll go and do some more learning before returning and adjusting the post. It's late where I am, I will fix this question.

Answer (score 0):

- For Android Device with Marshmallow, You Need to Specify the **[Run
  Time Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)** in Your Code Make Sure those example Projects
  Have this
- Try My Sample [Blutooth App](https://github.com/gotoark/SampleBluetoothApp)